# Non-linear multivariate analysis / partial least squares

Tags: multivariate-analysis, partial-least-squares

When dealing with multivariate analysis with variables that have a mix of linear and non-linear relationships (example: two variables are linearly related but one of these maybe non-linear with respect to a third variable), how can we determine the strength of these relationships?

How will this work with PLS because it is a linear method? Will certain variables be considered to have more influence because they fit a linear trend better than the other variables with poor linearity?

Are there any packages in R to deal with this?

To clarify: by non-linear, I am referring to everything that is not linear, both linear in parameter (exponential, Weibull etc) and linear in variable (linear, quadratic) (https://www.quora.com/Why-is-linear-regression-called-linear-if-we-can-use-quadratic-equations-in-our-model-which-gives-a-curved-line)

Comment: What do you mean by strength? Anyway, one way you could do this is by estimating the ratio of explained variance for each variable (for ex. ANOVA).

Comment: Why not add new variables in a non-linear manner? For example, add variable's square as a new variable and see how the model performs on an independent test set.